# Spark retrieve a number of feature values from a hive table and merge into a 2 dimensional array

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a hive table as below with Object ID, feature ID and feature values. And I have an array of feature IDs, with which I select their values for each object id

[image]

```
val arrFeat=Array("Fea1","Feat2","Feat3","Feat4","Feat5")
```

I would like to transform this dataframe into a two dimensional array below for machine learning.

```
Array(Array(1,2,3,4,5),Array(2,3,4,5,6),Array(3,4,5,6,7)...)
```

Each Array (row) inside represents feature values of a single object ID. For Now I did it this way

```
var dtfCompl=spark.sql("select distinct ObjectID,FeatureValue from Table " +
  " where FeatID='"+arrFeat(0)+"'" )

for (a<-1 to arrFeat.length-1){
  val strFeat=arrFeat(a)

  val dtfFeat1=spark.sql("select distinct ObjectID,FeatureValue from table " +
    " where bax='"+strFeat+"'")

  dtfCompl=dtfCompl.join(dtfFeat1,Seq("ObjectID"),"inner").cache()
}

   val arrXmea=dtfCompl.orderBy("ObjectID").drop("ObjectID").collect.map(x=>
  x.toSeq.toArray.map(y=>y.toString.toDouble)
)
```

Is there a better way of doing this, to avoid joining the dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

If in your fact table in column `FeatureID` you have features that you don't have in your arrFeat, then there is no other way, you need to pass the information, what should and what should not be selected.
I would not be afraid of join, assuming you have short feature dataframe, spark is clever enough to do map side join.

You can also group and collect list, something like this:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .appName("spark-app").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
val dfLabels = Seq("Fea1","Fea2","Fea3","Fea4","Fea5").toDF("FeatureID")
val df = Seq(
  ("A", "Fea1", 1),
  ("B", "Fea1", 2),
  ("C", "Fea1", 3),
  ("D", "Fea1", 4),
  ("A", "Fea2", 4),
  ("B", "Fea2", 6),
  ("C", "Fea2", 5),
  ("D", "Fea2", 5),
).toDF("ObjectID", "FeatureID", "FeatureValue")
val result = df.join(dfLabels, "FeatureID").groupBy("FeatureID").agg(collect_list("FeatureValue") as "Values")
result.show()
==
+---------+------------+
|FeatureID|      Values|
+---------+------------+
|     Fea2|[4, 6, 5, 5]|
|     Fea1|[1, 2, 3, 4]|
+---------+------------+
```

from which you can easily create array of array:

```scala
result.select("Values").as[Array[Int]].collect()
==
res1: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(4, 6, 5, 5), Array(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes this hive table is an invertory of objects' feature values and from time to time my arrFeat varies. I meant each 'sub' array inside the outer array represents one object's multiple feature IDs' values. The result you created, does one row represent values of one feature from all objects ?

Comment: @davidzxc574 yes, it does represent